# How to prevent session list from overlaying on top of what is being displayed on TeamViewer?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Somehow, my g key has become the shortcut to bring the session list to the front.

It is infuriating trying to type a paper and have a key rendered useless. Worst, I can't even figure out how to undo it. It just happened one day. Minimizing the session list doesn't do anything as hitting the "g" key will just highlight it.

Alternating g key stokes just minimizes and maximizes the session list. After doing some digging, I've found out the session list can't be disabled. Fine, but how do I untag a key to stop it from being highlighted?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of `Extras --> Options --> Advanced`

Answer (score 0):

Try in *Extras > Options > Advanced* to click “Show advanced options”
and tick “Automatically minimize local TeamViewer panel”, then OK.

I have no idea why the `g` key behaves so strangely.
The simplest way to reinitialize Teams would be to uninstall it,
clean out its folders, and reinstall.
You will need to login and set again all your options.